# How to find or parse html tag with namespace?

Tags: php, html-parsing, domdocument, phpquery, querypath

I'm trying to find custom html element with namespace but I could not get any success on it. I also checked other libraries like QueryPath, Ganon including phpQuery. Only PhpSimpleDom library can do this but I don't want to use it anymore. It's has memory problem and does not provide the full selector features.

Can anyone please help me on it?

See example below;

```
<plugin:color value="#000" />
```

Thanks in advance. 
Smac

Comment: You could start your own solution by using a "dirty approach" which would be treating the html code, wrapping it to convert it to a well-formed-XML-string with your html code as its contents, then you can use PHP DOM functions (http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) so you can iterate over the code such as an object, searching for any specific tags you might want or need.

Comment: Is that really html? Do you want to use the namespace to select it or just get any color?

Comment: I just want to use my own tagname with namespace like plugin:color for fetching the all attributes and etc.